# which was first execute in HTML file head or body?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML which was execute first head tag or body tag. I had this doubt while learing javascript and i need to include this file to the html so that.

Comment: whichever comes first while parsing the HTML.

Comment: Do you want to know which one executes first regardless of position? of which one you should place first in your html? the latter is the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes from top to bottom so the head executes first then the body, you can try it your self:

```
 <head>

    <title>test</title>
    <script> alert('From Head'); </script>

</head>
<body>

    <script>alert("From Body");</script> 

</body>
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Marox003/pen/Bjbwad)

Answer (score 1):

It goes from top down, calling each script it finds while parsing the whole HTML document (normally the head tag goes first, with all the scripts inside, in the order they were placed). So if you need to include JS files, always put the least dependant ones at the top.

Also, if your JS scripts access DOM elements, make sure the script runs *after* the DOM is ready, by either using a window onload callback or placing the script before closing the body tag (so it comes "after" the DOM stuff).